# How can I find unindexed foreign keys in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, foreign-keys

I have a SQL Server 2000 database with approximately 220 tables.  These tables have a number foreign key relationships between them.  Through performance analysis, we've discovered a number of these foreign key relationships are missing indexes.  Instead of being reactive to performance problems, I'd like to be pro-active and find all foreign keys that are missing indexes.

How can I programmatically determine which foreign key are missing indexes?

Comment: Missing or rarely used?  This article is for 2005, but could help: http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlcat/archive/2006/02/13/531339.aspx

Comment: Missing.  Rarely used is another interesting performance optimization, but not what I'm interested in here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an answer that works for SQL Server 2000 authored by a co-worker:

```
/*
Description:
    This script outputs a table with all the current database un-indexed foreign keys.

    The table has three columns ( TableName , ColumnName, ForeignKeyName ) 
    TableName: The table containing the un-indexed foreign key
    ColumnName: The foreign key column that’s not indexed 
    ForeignKeyName: Name of foreign key witch column doesn’t have an index 
    */
DECLARE 
    @TableName varchar(255),
    @ColumnName varchar(255),
    @ForeignKeyName sysname

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

DECLARE FKColumns_cursor CURSOR Fast_Forward FOR
SELECT  cu.TABLE_NAME, cu.COLUMN_NAME, cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS ic 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu ON ic.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE   ic.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'

CREATE TABLE #temp1(    
    TableName varchar(255),
    ColumnName varchar(255),
    ForeignKeyName sysname
)

OPEN FKColumns_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM FKColumns_cursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName, @ForeignKeyName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

    IF ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM    sysobjects o    
        INNER JOIN sysindexes x ON x.id = o.id
        INNER JOIN  syscolumns c ON o.id = c.id 
        INNER JOIN sysindexkeys xk ON c.colid = xk.colid AND o.id = xk.id AND x.indid = xk.indid
    WHERE   o.type in ('U')
        AND xk.keyno <= x.keycnt
        AND permissions(o.id, c.name) <> 0
        AND (x.status&32) = 0
        AND o.name = @TableName
        AND c.name = @ColumnName
    ) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #temp1 SELECT @TableName, @ColumnName, @ForeignKeyName
    END


    FETCH NEXT FROM FKColumns_cursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName, @ForeignKeyName
END  
CLOSE FKColumns_cursor  
DEALLOCATE FKColumns_cursor 

SELECT * FROM #temp1 ORDER BY TableName
```

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.foreign_keys fk
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
        WHERE   fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
                AND NOT EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    sys.index_columns ic
                WHERE   ic.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
                        AND ic.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
                        AND ic.index_column_id = fkc.constraint_column_id
                )
        )
```

I don't have a copy of `SQL Server 2000` handy, but you may need to change `sys.foreign_key` to `sysforeignkeys` etc., like described [`here`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187997(SQL.90).aspx).

This query selects all foreign keys which don't have an index covering all columns that comprise the key.

This supports multi-column foreign keys just as well.

This, however, will return a false positive if there is a composite index that covers all columns but they are not the leftmost columns in this index.

Like, if there is a `FOREIGN KEY (col2, col3)` and an index on `(col1, col2, col3)`, this will return that there is an index despite the fact this index is unusable for this foreign key.

Comment: This probably does what I want for SQL Server 2005 and later, but I haven't tested it.  I'll post the SQL Server 2000 equivalent when I convert it.

Comment: I would also have `AND ic.index_column_id = fkc.constraint_column_id` in the NOT EXISTS to ensure the index is in the correct index key column order too. Otherwise, exactly what I use day to day

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Built on the above code to drop the temp table and get scripts to create the indexes.

```
   /*
Description:

    */
DECLARE 
    @SchemaName varchar(255),
    @TableName varchar(255),
    @ColumnName varchar(255),
    @ForeignKeyName sysname

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

DECLARE FKColumns_cursor CURSOR Fast_Forward FOR
SELECT  cu.TABLE_SCHEMA, cu.TABLE_NAME, cu.COLUMN_NAME, cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS ic 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu ON ic.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE   ic.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'

CREATE TABLE #temp1(    
    SchemaName varchar(255),
    TableName varchar(255),
    ColumnName varchar(255),
    ForeignKeyName sysname
)

OPEN FKColumns_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM FKColumns_cursor INTO @SchemaName,@TableName, @ColumnName, @ForeignKeyName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

    IF ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM        sysobjects o    
        INNER JOIN sysindexes x ON x.id = o.id
        INNER JOIN  syscolumns c ON o.id = c.id 
        INNER JOIN sysindexkeys xk ON c.colid = xk.colid AND o.id = xk.id AND x.indid = xk.indid
    WHERE       o.type in ('U')
        AND xk.keyno <= x.keycnt
        AND permissions(o.id, c.name) <> 0
        AND (x.status&32) = 0
        AND o.name = @TableName
        AND c.name = @ColumnName
    ) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #temp1 SELECT @SchemaName, @TableName, @ColumnName, @ForeignKeyName
    END


    FETCH NEXT FROM FKColumns_cursor INTO @SchemaName,@TableName, @ColumnName, @ForeignKeyName
END  
CLOSE FKColumns_cursor  
DEALLOCATE FKColumns_cursor 

SELECT 'CREATE INDEX IDX_' + ForeignKeyName + ' ON ' + SchemaName + '.' + TableName + '(' + ColumnName +')'
FROM #temp1 
ORDER BY TableName

drop table #temp1
```

Answer (score 1):

In my post ["SQL Script to create indexes for Foreign keys"](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2011/06/05/sql-script-to-create-indexes-for-foreign-keys.aspx) I've put links to 2 implementations: [paul_nielsen](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2007/02/08/codegen-to-create-indexes-for-fks.aspx)’s and [tklimczak's (login to sqlservercentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Index+Management/62069/) is required)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: list the columns with a foreign key constraint. This will help:

[Query to get all foreign key constraints in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831589/query-to-get-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sqlserver-2000)

Cross-compare with `sysindexes` and `syscolumns` tables; the `keys` field in `sysindexes` has a list of all keys in the index.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is for SQL Server 2005+ but this was the only question I found about this topic.

```
--Finds foreign keys without indexes
--How to interpret:
--When we delete frpm PkTable, it checks FkColumn for the PkId we are deleting.
--So if FkTable doesn't have an index on FkColumn, then we cannot delete a row from PkTable because it is too slow.
SELECT  rt.name as PkTableName, rc.name as PkColumnName,
fk.name FkName, t.name as FkTableName, c.name as FkColumnName, ddps.row_count, i.name as IndexName
FROM    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
inner join sys.foreign_keys fk on fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
inner join sys.tables t on fkc.parent_object_id = t.object_id
inner join sys.columns c on fkc.parent_object_id = c.object_id and fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
inner join sys.tables rt on fkc.referenced_object_id = rt.object_id
inner join sys.columns rc on fkc.referenced_object_id = rc.object_id and fkc.referenced_column_id = rc.column_id
inner join sys.indexes ri on t.object_id = ri.object_id
inner JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps ON ri.OBJECT_ID = ddps.OBJECT_ID AND ri.index_id = ddps.index_id 
left join sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = t.object_id and ic.column_id = c.column_id
left join sys.indexes i on ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.index_id = ic.index_id
where ri.index_id < 2 and i.index_id is null and ddps.row_count > 0
order by 
--PkTableName,
ddps.row_count desc
```